# List with two columns - using partial search

Tags: linq, list

I have a list with 2 columns  and trying to use contains to search partially.
Emp contains id and name.

```
var list = new List<Emp>();
list = list.Any(o => o.Contains(new Emp{ Name = name }));
```

However it is throwing an error: 
cannot convert from Emp to system.Linq. Iqueryable

any input on this will be helpful

Thanks in advance

Comment: It doesn't help that you haven't shown your `Emp` class...

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear what exactly you're trying to do. You might want:

```
list = list.Where(emp => emp.Name == name).ToList();
```

or perhaps

```
list = list.Where(emp => emp.Name.Contains(name)).ToList();
```

It's not at all clear why you'd be trying to use `Any` though.

EDIT: Given the comment, I suspect you really want:

```
list = list.Where(emp => emp.Name.StartsWith(name)).ToList();
```

(You might need to make it case-insensitive though.)

Or if you need to check each part of the name, you could either use a regular expression or:

```
list = list.Where(emp => emp.Name.Split(' ')
                            .Any(x => x.StartsWith(name))).ToList();
```

This last approach will be *really* inefficient though, as it will split each name each time you look through it... you could potentially make your `Emp` objects immutable and cache the split form. Or look into a regular expression version. Either way, you probably don't just want `string.Contains` as that will find matches *anywhere* in the name.

Comment: I have a text box to enter name - when I enter a letter, it should display all the names starting with that letter. It is like a partial search of that name. So was using Contains.

Comment: @testacc: That means you want `StartsWith`, not `Contains`.

Comment: Above one is not working as I am partially searching for that letter

Comment: @testacc: What do you mean by "above one"? I originally gave two snippets of code, and I've now given three. I suspect you want the last one... but you really need to *understand* the answer so you can adapt it yourself, rather than needing everything to be given to you verbatim.

Comment: In case you want implementation as it happens in google where it suggest the correct word on typing then this would be an inefficient, due to linear search in the list, consider a custom DS, I think they internally use Trie check this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/640998/NET-Data-Structures-for-Prefix-String-Search-and-S

Comment: @Jon Skeet I am in the learning phase. I cannot use StartsWith because that  letter may be the start of the second word too.Sorry for not making it clear For ex:If I take your name itself and I search for S, It should display your name

Comment: You can use Pattern matching (Regular expression), but again List will be a bad DS for lot of records due to O(n) complexity

Comment: @testacc: This is where it's important to be precise. You may well need a regular expression in order to look for things at the start of each name. Then you need to consider the case where the user has typed the whole name, including a space.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj: O(n) complexity isn't a problem if there's a small number of names. Given that the OP is a relative beginner by the looks of it, I don't think performance is going to be the primary concern right now. I'd *at least* wait until they've got a working simple solution before adding more complexity in the name of optimization.

Comment: @Jon agreed but just think every addition / deletion will go through whole list again and again, yes for small number that's fine, but I have seen such implementations creating big bottlenecks for whole application

Comment: @MrinalKamboj: By "addition / deletion" do you mean "of what the user has typed"? If so, I agree it will be O(n) - but I still think it's more appropriate to focus on correctness first. Wading into complex approaches when the OP's current situation is a compile-time failure when attempting a simple approach doesn't seem like a good idea to me.

Comment: @Jon agreed with your approach, I myself have learned a lot from your book and plural sight tutorials